# Rails Single Sign On

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on, doorkeeper

I'm kinda stuck right now with how to use single sign on in a specific scenario. So what I need to have is the following:

- Apple Id like SSO (using rails)
- Multiple rails api apps with seperate react frontends
- Ability to activate/deactivate access to the apps

I've been using the doorkeeper gem so far but I don't know how to limit (activate/deactivate) access to the applications.

Hope somebody can help me out!